# Wrong type operation when attempting to LPOP from a list in redis

Tags: go, redis, tdd, go-redis

I'm playing around with redis using golang but i keep getting an error when i attempt to `LPOP` an element from the list. It works only when i insert the first element in the list but when i attempt to add the second element i keep getting the error below:
`WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value`

I have read the documentation but i'm still getting this error please could anyone point to what i'm doing wrong as i'm still debugging. Thanks

```
testCases := []struct{
       name string
       key  string
       val  string
    } {
       {
         name: "one",
         key:  "color",
         val: "red",
       },
       {
         name: "two"
         key:  "color",
         val: "blue",
      },
      {
         name: "three"
         key:  "color",
         val: "purple",
      },
    }

    for _, tc := range testCases {
       t.Run(tc.name, func(t *testing.T){
          rc := redis.NewClient{} // params added
          defer rc.Close()
          err := rc.Send("RPUSH", tc.key, tc.val)
          require.NoError(t, err)

          err = rc.Flush()
          require.NoError(t, err)

          v, err = redis.String(rc.Do("LPOP", tc.key))
          require.NoError(t, err)
          assert.Exact(t, tc.val, v)

         _, err = rc.Do("SETEX", tc.key, 10, tc.val)
         require.NoError(t, err)
       })
    }
```

Comment: One of the keys already exists and it is not a list.  To debug, call [TYPE tc.key](https://redis.io/commands/type) before attempting to RPUSH.  Also, rc.Send / rc.Flush can be replaced with a single call to rc.Do.

Comment: @CeriseLimón thanks for the response but i thought `RPUSH` will append to the list regardless if the key does exist?

Comment: I am saying that a key exists and the value of the key is not a "list". The first paragraph of the RPUSH documentation says "*When key holds a value that is not a list, an error is returned.*"

Comment: @CeriseLimón thanks on the tip on checking the type. When it runs the i do get type as list when `one` runs but when `two` runs it returns the type as a string.

Comment: @CeriseLimón thanks i know what i'm doing wrong after i `RPUSH` im calling a `SET` directly after which is why i'm getting a string.

Comment: @CeriseLimón sorry i updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

The [RPUSH documentation says](https://redis.io/commands/rpush):

> When key holds a value that is not a list, an error is returned.

At the end of the first iteration of the loop, the application sets "color" to a string value using the SETEX command.

The RPUSH to "color" at beginning of the second iteration fails because "color" is not a list.